# cut & to fields 1 & 2 from file_A and use them as the pattern for a line in file_B and echo results

Tags: sed, awk, grep, field, cut

I have 2 very large files (over 900 meg each) that are formatted as

```
email@address.tld:some_string:full name:location:contract_number
```

I need to use both fields 1 & 2 from file_A (chk.forward.AUDIT.DATA.SET) as the patterns to match against fields 1 & 2 in a single line from file_b (AUDIT.DATA.SET). I am open to using sed, awk, grep, cut, or any thing that will speed up execution.

Below is my poorly written command.I have a error in here that is creating a monster sized results file (bigger then the original files). I am sure there is a much better way of doing this.

```
while read line; do grep $(echo $line | cut -d: -f2) AUDIT.DATA.SET
>/dev/null && echo "AUDIT PASS ACCOUNT:$(echo $line | cut -d: -f1) FORWARD:$(echo $line | cut -d: -f2) MATCH OVD RECORD $(grep $(echo $line |cut -d: -f2) AUDIT.DATA.SET)" &  || echo "AUDIT FAIL ACCOUNT:$(echo $line | cut -d: -f1) FORWARD:$(echo $line | cut -d:
-f2) NO MATCH $(grep $(echo $line |cut -d: -f2) AUDIT.DATA.SET)"  ; done < chk.forward.AUDIT.DATA.SET >> restuls.txt
```

Comment: Whats your expected output? You mentioned 2 files but provided format of just one.

Comment: they are the format.  thank yo for asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume that your two files have same format, as you explained in question. you could try with awk's association array:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2];next}$1$2 in a' file_a file_b > result.txt
```

the line above will save all matched result in result.txt. It finds all rows in file_b, which column1 and column2 existed in file_a.

Comment: Kent,thank you, how can I modify this awk line to add the failed to match and echo Matched or No Match ?

Comment: `awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2];next}$1$2 in a{print > "matched";next}{print > "failed"' file_a file_b`  try this. didn't test, but should work. hopefully. :D after execution that line you have two files `matched` and `failed`

Comment: Kent,  got a error on run. I think error is cast prior to output to files as matched and failed are not created.                                     awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>>  <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
 missing }

Comment: @user2455949 yes a `}` is missing. just add a `}` after `"failed"'` and before `file_a` .  sorry

Comment: no need to be sorry Kent you are helping me. bad news, looks like all went to failed file.

Comment: @EvilGenius glad to help. would be nice if you could accept the answer.

Comment: sorry for the delay Kent, I am evil you know....  one question... It seems as if the order of File_A or File_B does not matter in the context of your suggested command, is that correct (which would be awesome!)